# Zoom scroll page

Tags: javascript, three.js, dom-events

I have a problem when I zoom on my html page : I'm using threejs library to implement the zoom function; however when I zoom on the page, zoom scrols the page; there's a way to disable page scrolling when I zoom: this is my code:

```
function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
    if (ZoomOut && event.wheelDeltaY<0) {
        camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
        if(camera.fov<-1 || camera.fov>180){
            //alert(camera.fov);
            camera.fov=50;
        }
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    if (ZoomIn && event.wheelDeltaY>0) {
        camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
        if(camera.fov<-1 || camera.fov>180){
            //alert(camera.fov);
            camera.fov=50;
        }
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the page that is giving you problems?

Comment: This problem is releted to a my project. I could sent you my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely can be fixed with a CSS setting.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it's a good solution  but i desable scrolling just when i zoom the page; a better solution?

Comment: What I proposed is the usual solution. You can change it dynamically with javascript if you want.